# Removing the first letter from every word and creating a list but not the first letter of specific stopwords

Tags: python

This is the assignment: Write code that uses the string stored in org and creates an acronym which is assigned to the variable acro. Only the first letter of each word should be used, each letter in the acronym should be a capital letter, and there should be nothing to separate the letters of the acronym. Words that should not be included in the acronym are stored in the list stopwords. For example, if org was assigned the string “hello to world” then the resulting acronym should be “HW”.

So I have managed to get the first letters from every word in the sentence but that includes the stopwords list, how do I remove those from my final result?

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
org = "The organization for health, safety, and education"
acro = ''
acro = [i[0] for i in org.upper().split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to have logic in a list comprehension, so you can do something like

```
acro = [i[0] for i in org.upper().split(' ') if i.lower() not in stopwords]
```

Comment: Nice answer, very simple

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` in a list-comprehension and `join` at the end to form string:

```
org = 'hello to world'
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
acro = ''

print(acro.join([x[0].upper() for x in org.split() if x.lower() not in stopwords]))
# HW
```

Or with `map` + `lambda` (*for fun*):

```
acro.join(map(lambda x: x[0].upper() if x.lower() not in stopwords else '', org.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
org = "The organization for health, safety, and education"

acro  = ""
for i in org.split(" "):
    if i not in stopwords:
        acro = acro + i[0].upper()

print(acro)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your stop words are not all in lower case. Something like this will do:

```
org =  "The organization for health, safety, and education"
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]

acro = [i[0].upper() for i in org.split(' ') if i not in stopwords]
print(''.join(acro))
```

which returns 'OHSE'.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an assignment and you want to understand what happens, maybe it's good to do it step-by-step:

```
acro_temp = [i for i in org.split(' ')]                  # convert to array
acro_temp = [i for i in acro_temp if i not in stopwords] # remove stopwords
acro_temp = [i.upper() for i in acro_temp]               # make the words uppercase
acro = [i[0] for i in acro_temp]                         # use only first letter
```

And then to compress it, you can use the suggestion of @TheStrangeQuark.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.  Your stopwords list should contain case insensitive entries (i.e. all uppercase or all lowercase).   You only need to add an if condition to your list comprehension.

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
org = "The organization for health, safety, and education"
stopwords = set( w.upper() for w in stopwords )
acro = [i[0] for i in org.upper().split(' ') if i not in stopwords]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
org = "The organization for health, safety, and education"
org_split = org.split(' ')
acro = ''

for letter in org_split:
    if letter.lower() not in stopwords:
        letter = letter[0].upper()
        acro += acro.join(letter)
print(acro)
```

this will get you 'OHSE' others get ['O', 'H', 'S', 'E']. both are technically correct so it depends what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```py
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', 'The']
sent = "The water earth and air are vital"

acro = ""
sent_words = sent.split()
for word in sent_words:
    if word not in stopwords:
        acro = acro + word[:2]
        if word != sent_words[-1]:
            acro += ". "
acro = acro.upper()
print(acro)
```